# Difference between "believe in" and "believe"

Tags: prepositions, difference

What's the difference between "believe" and "believe in" in the following sentences?

> I.
>   **Kate**: Hey, John, do you **believe in** black magic and astrology?
>   **John**: No, I don't **believe in** all those things.
>
> II.
>   **Kate**: Hey, John, do you **believe in** black magic and astrology?
>   **John**: No, I don't **believe** all those things.

Answer (score 4):

We believe a statement, that it is true.

We believe a person (who has spoken), that what they say is true.

We believe in a person (we have faith in them or trust them).

We believe in [the existence of] something, that it is real.

Astrology makes predictions, and thus is in some ways it is like a statement. Both of these would be idiomatic:

> I don't believe astrology.
>
> I don't believe in astrology.

But "magic" makes no statements. This would be not be idiomatic:

> I don't believe magic.  <sup>unidiomatic</sup>

Comment: So can I use both of them in the sentence?

Comment: What sentence are you speaking of? There are several in your question.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=believed+astrology%2Cbelieved+in+astrology&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelieved%20astrology%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelieved%20in%20astrology%3B%2Cc0), *to believe astrology* is vanishingly rare compared to *to believe **in** astrology*. That's because astrology is a *source of knowledge* and/or *entity whose "existence" may be doubted*, rather than an actual *statement* (whose *veracity* may be open to question).

Comment: @FumbleFingers:I don't think we can rely on ngram here inasmuch as "I don't believe astrology" is a colloquialism not likely to finds its way into print. I don't doubt that "believe in" occurs far more often.  And I said "in some ways it is like a statement", not that it was a statement.  I'm merely attempting to explain the usage.  I do believe in astrology.  You shouldn't go outdoors next week.

Comment: I specifically searched for ***believed** [in] astrology* because that's more likely to occur in "formal" contexts than the first person assertion. Obviously you *can* actually say *I don't believe astrology* with no preposition, but that changes the meaning somewhat. Effectively, to *I don't believe **the claims astrologers make***, whereas the more common ***in*** version has more the sense of *I don't believe **that astrology is based on truth*** (that it "exists" as a reliable source of truth). One might make a similar distinction in *I don't believe [in] God.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Obviously you can actually say I don't believe astrology with no preposition, but that changes the meaning somewhat. " Exactly the point I was making in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

believe in spirits

believe in ghosts

believe in God

believe **(in)** you/her/him/them

believe in this method of teaching

believe in early rising

believe in marrying young

believe astrology or believe in astrology ?

I could think 'believe in' means 'accept as true' or 'accept as good' or 'accept as being'.

I feel 'believe (in) astrology'.

Language is not a science and it is a living creature: be born, has been living, be dead

Language is only just 'a promise' agreed among specific group of people(s).

We can not promise (in) everything.

Comment: "I feel 'believe (in) astrology'. " You feel… what?

Comment: feel both of them can be used and it depends on the user of the language